# JSLink code to filter lookup columns work on a Custom list's new and edit item form but not on document library edit item form

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink, client-side-rendering

I am using JSLink code to filter lookup column to show relevant values. The same code works well on a custom list's edit form but breaks on the document library's edit form. I checked the ID of lookup column and its consistent across document library and custom list. Below is the code I am using, can someone please help me out to determine why its not working on a library edit form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var FilterLookupHandler = (function () {
        var handler = function (fieldInternalName, queryField) {
            this.internalName = fieldInternalName;
            this.showField = queryField;
            this.suggestions = [];
            this.listId = "";
            this.currentValue;
        }
        handler.prototype.render = function (rCtx, field) {
            var self = this;
            self.renderContext = rCtx;
            if (rCtx != null && rCtx.CurrentItem != null) {
                var stringValue = rCtx.CurrentItem[rCtx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
                //self.currentValue = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
                //if (stringValue) {
                //    self.currentValue.set_lookupId(stringValue.split(";#")[0])
                //    stringValue = stringValue.split(";#")[1]
                //}
                self.listId = rCtx.CurrentFieldSchema.LookupListId;
            }
            if (rCtx == null || rCtx.CurrentFieldValue == null)
                return '';
            var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(rCtx);
            if (formCtx == null || formCtx.fieldSchema == null)
                return '';
            self.formCtx = formCtx;
            self.registerCallbacks();
            var htmlString = "";
            htmlString += "<select id='" + self.internalName + "_select'></select>";

            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
                execCallFoItems(self);
            });
            return htmlString;
        }

        function execCallFoItems(handler) {
            handler.callForItems("Kensington Estates", "Eq");
        }
        handler.prototype.callForItems = function (filterValue, tag) {
            var self = this;
            var cctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var list = cctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(new SP.Guid(self.listId));
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><' + tag + '><FieldRef Name=\'' + self.showField + '\'/>' +
                '<Value Type=\'Text\'>' + filterValue + '</Value></Geq></' + tag + '></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
            self.suggestedItems = list.getItems(query);
            cctx.load(self.suggestedItems)
            cctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(self, self.suggestionsLoaded, Function.createDelegate(self, self.callFailed)))
        }
        handler.prototype.suggestionsLoaded = function (sender, args) {
            var self = this;
            var itemsEnumerator = self.suggestedItems.getEnumerator();
            self.suggestions = [];
            while (itemsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var item = itemsEnumerator.get_current();
                self.suggestions.push({
                    id: item.get_item("ID"),
                    value: item.get_item(self.internalName)
                })
            }
            self.updateSuggestions();
        }
        handler.prototype.updateSuggestions = function () {
            var self = this;
            var selectElement = document.getElementById(self.internalName + "_select");
            var optionsHtml = "";
            var liHtml = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < self.suggestions.length; i++) {
                var suggestion = self.suggestions[i];
                optionsHtml += "<option value='" + suggestion.id + "'>" + suggestion.value + "</option>";
                liHtml += "<li>" + suggestion.value + "</li>"
            }

            selectElement.innerHTML = optionsHtml;
            selectElement.onchange();
        }
        handler.prototype.callFailed = function (sender, args) {
            alert(args.get_message())
        }
        handler.prototype.registerCallbacks = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(self.formCtx.fieldName, function () {
                return self.getCurrentValue();
            });
        }
        handler.prototype.getCurrentValue = function () {
            var selectedValue = document.getElementById(this.internalName + "_select").value;
            //this.currentValue.set_lookupId(selectedValue);
            //return this.currentValue;
            return selectedValue;
        }
        return handler;
    })();  


    (function () {
        if (typeof SPClientTemplates === 'undefined')
            return;
        var officeFieldHandler = new FilterLookupHandler("Company","Title");
        var OfficeFieldContext = {};
        OfficeFieldContext.Templates = {};
        OfficeFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {
            'Company1': {
                'EditForm': Function.createDelegate(officeFieldHandler, officeFieldHandler.render),
                'NewForm': Function.createDelegate(officeFieldHandler, officeFieldHandler.render)
            }
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(OfficeFieldContext);
    })();  
</script>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Per my test, it works in library EditForm.aspx.

Are you using the same list as the source list of the lookup column?

The “**Company1**” from the code below is the column’s **internal name**. Ensure the internal name of your column in the document library is “**Company1**”.

```
OfficeFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {
            'Company1': {
                'EditForm': Function.createDelegate(officeFieldHandler, officeFieldHandler.render),
                'NewForm': Function.createDelegate(officeFieldHandler, officeFieldHandler.render)
            }
        };
```

To get the actual internal name for your column, browsing to the library Settings > Edit Column and look at the path.

The path will be like:

```
<site>/_layouts/15/FldEditEx.aspx?List=%7B<list GUID>%7D&Field=<column internal name>
```

[image]

Comment: I got it to work. The source list was residing at root site so I had to change to pass the root site url to get that context. One issue I have is duplicate values in the lookup column which is because of the source list, is there a way to change this so it only shows unique values by integrating some piece of code in this existing code?

Comment: As it is new question, you can post a new thread for it.

Comment: Just posted it as a new question